# Is $\langle\ a,b\ \vert\ aba=bab,\ abab=baba\ \rangle$ a presentation of the free group on a single generator?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Is the following a presentation of the free group generated by a single element?

> $\langle\ a,b\ \vert\ aba=bab,\ abab=baba\ \rangle.$

My thinking is the following:

> $abab = baba=b(bab)=b^2ab$ by substituting the first relation into the second. Simplifying, we get $a=b$. Since these steps give equivalent statements, the above presentation is in fact $\langle\ a,b\ \vert\ a=b\ \rangle$, *i.e.*, the free group on one generator.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes , What you have said its correct

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers using the checkmark $\checkmark$ symbol :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is correct.

One thing I would leave out is the $b^2ab$ step, for $a=b$ follows from $abab=b(bab)$ by cancelling $bab$ on the right.